# sbt: Prevent erroneous command being issued?

Tags: sbt

I have an sbt project in which the build is normally invoked via `package-tar`. If a developer types `package`, it's very likely that they actually meant `package-tar` instead.

However, `package-tar` depends on `package`. How can I prevent or deter or warn when a developer seems to be making this mistake - since I can't actually *disable* the `package` task because it's necessary?

I considered integrating actual deployment into the build, but this is not compatible with our current deployment process.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making `package-tar` a separate task, how about just redefining `package` to do what you want? The new behavior can invoke the old behavior.

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Detailed-Topics/Artifacts.html has examples of customizing what `package` does. The material on `addArtifact` looks relevant.